# How to prevent Normal users from terminating process?

Tags: c++, windows, console-application

How to keep users from terminating process??

```
   static BOOL WINAPI console_ctrl_handler(DWORD dwCtrlType)
    {
      switch (dwCtrlType)
      {
      case CTRL_C_EVENT: // Ctrl+C
          { 

              break;
            //return TRUE;
          }

      case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT: // Ctrl+Break
        break;
      case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT: // Closing the console window //event was caught
//But I guess call exitProcess ()
        break;
        //return TRUE;  
      case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT: // User logs off. Passed only to services!
        break;
      case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT: // System is shutting down. Passed only to services!
        break;
      }

      // Return TRUE if handled this message, further handler functions won't be called.
      // Return FALSE to pass this message to further handlers until default handler calls ExitProcess().
      return TRUE;
    }
```

It is my SetConsoleCtrlHandler handler.
when I was debugging CTRL_C_EVENT successfully return true so it was ignored.

But CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT was also caught , and return TRUE but exited

What is the problem??

It is my solution that If handler catches CLOSE_WINDOW event ,

then CreateProcess that is identical.

So anybody who wants the same thing what I want, just apply this to your program.

```
BOOL WINAPI console_ctrl_handler(DWORD dwCtrlType){

    HANDLE current_process= GetCurrentProcess();//

    char filePath[MAX_PATH]="";

    DWORD size=MAX_PATH;

    QueryFullProcessImageName(current_process,0,filePath,&size);//

    STARTUPINFO startupInfo = {0};
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;

    switch (dwCtrlType){

    case CTRL_C_EVENT: // Ctrl+C

          break;

    case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT: // Closing the console window //
      //
    system("cls");//

    CreateProcess(
    filePath,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  FALSE,
  NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  &startupInfo,
  &processInformation
);  

      break; //

    case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT: // Ctrl+Break
    break;

    case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT: // User logs off. Passed only to services!
    break;

    case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT: // System is shutting down. Passed only to services!
    break;
  }//switch

  // Return TRUE if handled this message, further handler functions won't be called.
  // Return FALSE to pass this message to further handlers until default handler calls ExitProcess().
  return TRUE;

}
```

Comment: If you don't need interactivity run as a system service with auto-run. only admins can change system services.

Comment: @user1829967 If a user starts a process, he needs to be able to terminate it. So an application should not have the ability to prevent exiting. If your approach worked, then not even admin would be able to terminate it.

Comment: How Do you think above code?

Comment: Above code is totally addressing my problem....

Comment: @user1829967 I was fully able to C-A-D it. You can always kill a process if it is yours. And if not, you do not need to worry. Only its owner or the system administrator is able to kill it. And they can always kill it.

Comment: @user1829967 I would use GetModuleFileName instead of  QueryFullProcessImageName. The former will work on any Win32 implementation except possibly the very limited Win32s

Comment: Rather than editing your solution into the question, please post it as an answer.  However, a better solution is to build your program as a GUI program rather than as a console.  You don't have to actually provide a GUI if the program doesn't need one, and if you do, you can choose whether to present a close option or not.

Comment: ... But as long as the process is running as the current user, it can be killed anyway. The only way is to make the process run as a different user.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your program into a Windows service[1]. A Windows service runs in the background so there is no close button. They can also run as another user so regular users cannot terminate it.

Many services runs under high privileges. It is also possible to run the service as another user than administrator, which may be desired.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I edited my question, I caught close event
And want to just keep going

Comment: @user1829967: Why not a service? The only way is to let the process run as another user. And that requires a service.

Comment: I posted my solution, it is create new process.
on our environment, we just doesn't want to set system configuration.